# How to partially copy a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like this:

```
[ 1 2
  3 4
  5 6
  7 8 ]
```

Is there a way to copy in a variable, second line to the end, 3rd line to the end... to have:

second=

```
[ 3 4
  5 6
  7 8 ]
```

third=

```
[ 5 6
  7 8 ]
```

If so, how?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85564).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB uses parentheses for indexing

```
A = [1 2;
     3 4;
     5 6;
     7 8];
second = A(2:end, :);
third = A(3:end, :);
```

In the code above, for a 2D array (matrix), the first element in the parentheses selects rows and the second element selects columns. `end` automatically converted into the length of a corresponding axis. And `:` without anything means `select all along this axis`.